# Select a contiguous group of html elements with XPath

Tags: xpath, moovweb, tritium

I'm using Moovweb SDK and I want to apply a Tritium function I wrote to each group of contiguous elements with a certain classname. 
Given a flat hierarchy of html elements, how should I go about selecting only the groups of elements that appear in a row with XPath?

It's important that I select the groups of contiguous elements and not just all the elements because I'll be applying classnames and styles based on their index relative to the first preceding `<h2>`.

```
<h2>Blah</h2>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<h2>Blah</h2>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<h2>Blah</h2>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
<span class="hi">hi</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$(".//h2") {
  %x = text()
  do_something("./following-sibling::span[preceding-sibling::h2[1][.='"+%x+"'] and contains(@class,'hi')]")
}
```

What it's doing is grabbing each h2's text and comparing the spans' previous sibling h2's text to it. So it will only select spans between the different h2's (do_something is the custom Tritium function)

Note: this skips over any other types of nodes that may be in between the h2's.

EDIT: I changed

```
("./following-sibling::span[preceding-sibling::h2[1][.='"+%x+"']][@class='hi']")
```

to

```
("./following-sibling::span[preceding-sibling::h2[1][.='"+%x+"'] and contains(@class,'hi')]")
```

see this example: http://play.tritium.io/192d6bd9af3fcd1c26bb6487cb10c599eabbef83

thank you noj

Comment: given the example HTML above, wouldn't a simple xpath like `do_something(".//span[@class='hi']")` achieve the same thing?

Comment: This does not seem to work as described.
Here's an example:
http://play.tritium.io/c702492ed09e069ded4e0ae50a7e31c79110b1cd

It looks like the latter xpath is applying to all spans, not just the ones inbetween the <h2> tags.

Comment: tdesikan: do_something(".//span[@class='hi']") would select all of the spans as a single group and the cycle through all of the spans one by one. I wanted an xpath that would select and group only the contiguous spans, cycle through one contiguous group, then cycle through the next, etc. Because each group of nodes the xpath cycles through, the index() for each node is reset and that's what I wanted.